# Python : putting functions into classes

Tags: python, function, class

I am somewhat new to Python and I would like to understand classes a little bit better.  Below are a few functions which have a lot of similarities but different functions that are passed into each `multiprocessing` function.  Is there anyway that I can put all of these functions into a `class` called `FruitPie`?

```
def apple():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
        pool.map(func1, same_list)
        pool.close()

def banana():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
        pool.map(func2, same_list)
        pool.close()

def orange():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
        pool.map(func3, same_list)
        pool.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each function is so similar you can create a method that accepts the function to run (see `_run_pool()` below):

```
class FruitPie(object):
    def __init__(self, same_list):
        self.same_list = same_list

    def _run_pool(self, func):
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
        pool.map(func, self.same_list)
        pool.close()

    def apple(self):
        self._run_pool(func1)

    def banana(self):
        self._run_pool(func2)

    def orange(self):
        self._run_pool(func3)

# use like this...
pie = FruitPie(same_list)
pie.apple()
pie.banana()
pie.orange()
```

I'd be inclined, however, to do something like this which uses a dictionary to dispatch to a function given a fruit name:

```
class FruitPie(object):
    funcs = {'apple': func1, 'banana': func2, 'orange', func3}

    def __init__(self, same_list):
        self.same_list = same_list

    def run_pool(self, fruit):
        pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
        pool.map(FruitPie.funcs[fruit], self.same_list)
        pool.close()

# use like this...
pie = FruitPie(same_list)
for fruit in 'apple', 'banana', 'orange':
    pie.run_pool(fruit)
```

Comment: The first one allows you to call a function based on the class tho such as `pie.apple()`  where as the second example you gave will run all of them simultaneously?

Comment: Both examples are equivalent. The second does not run them simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean to do something like:

```
class FruitPie:
    def __init__(self, arguments):
        self.same_list = arguments

    def apple(self):
        # in python3.3+ you can use the with statement with Pools
        with mp.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
            pool.map(func1, self.same_list)

    def banana(self):
        with mp.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
            pool.map(func2, self.same_list)

    def orange(self):
        with mp.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
            pool.map(func3, self.same_list)
```

Which you can use as:

```
# this if is needed only at module level, not everytime you create a pool.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pie = FruitPie(['some', 'arguments'])
    pie.apple()
    pie.banana()
    pie.orange()
```

Note that when creating a class you have to explicitly reference the instance using `self`.

Comment: this even can be simplified with creating a function which will accept func1, func2 or func3 as the difference in apple, banana and orange is only in the function which is passed to map as first param

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Object Oriented Programming is not just about putting functions together in a class. An object should represent an entity (real or virtual), that provide all the behaviors associated with it, encapsulating its internal implementations.

Secondly, Method names(or function name for that matter) should be a verb not a Noun, while class(representing an entity should be noun).

Thirdly, This is an example of polymorphic behavior

A simple(naive) implementation could look like this -

```
class Fruit(object):
      """ An abstract class"""

      func = None

      def process(self, arguments):
          with mp.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
               pool.map(self.func, arguments)

class Apple(Fruit):

      func = func1

class Banana(Fruit):

      func = func2

class Orange(Fruit):

      func = func3

class FruitPie(object):

      def __init__(self, fruits):
          self.fruits = fruits

      def process(self, arguments):
          for fruit in self.fruits:
              fruit.process(arguments)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     pie = FruitPie(Apple(), Banana(), Orange())
     pie.process()
```

It is not a perfect design, there can be lot of improvements depending on the requirements of class which I'm not full aware of. But something on these lines.